# Which R functions are not suitable for programmatic use?

Tags: r, interactive

Some functions like `browser` only make sense when used interactively.

It is widely regarded that the `subset` function [should only be used interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9860090/134830).

Similarly, `sapply` isn't good for programmatic use since it doesn't simplify the result for zero length inputs.

I'm trying to make an exhaustive list of functions that are only not suitable for programmatic use.

The plan is to make a tool for package checking to see if any of these functions are called and give a warning.

There are other functions like `file.choose` and `readline` that require interactivity, but these are OK to include in packages, since the end use will be interactive.  I don't care too much about these for this use case but feel free to add them to the list.

Which functions have I missed?

Comment: imho `attach` should never be used, but especially not programmatically. And there are of course `View`, `edit` and friends. I'm not sure I agree with `sapply`.

Comment: @Roland Agreed with `attach`.  My view on `sapply` is that it causes too many obscure bugs due to zero-length inputs. E.g., `sapply(x, length)` returns an integer vector unless `x` has length `0`, in which case you get a list. If you know that the size of the output is constant then use `vapply`, otherwise use `lapply`.

Comment: Incidentally, my motivation for this question is that I keep accidentally leaving calls to `browser` in my code, which looks silly if you check it into a repository.

Comment: Maybe you should also warn against `cat`. Often `message` should be used instead.

Comment: sapply is a special case of lapply anyway

Comment: This may be a bit drastic.  The problem with functions such as `subset` when used in programming is that they use non-standard evaluation of their arguments.  This is only a potential problem if those arguments that are evaluated using non-standard evaluation are passed variables.  Such functions can still be used safely in functions if the arguments subject to non-standard evaluation are passed constant expressions.  For example,  `subset(data, id == 1)` would not be a problem in a function.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck OK, `subset` isn't very dangerous. One thing that would be amazing for R would be to have MATLAB's automated code checking and fixing facility. http://bit.ly/1iqehBz This which-functions-should-I-avoid idea is the "what can I build in a day?" equivalent.

Comment: This almost goes without saying, but in case any new R users are looking at this answer, avoid "for" loops since they are very slow.

Comment: @Roland It just so happens that [I have a case where `attach` is required](https://github.com/klmr/modules/blob/e5e947ce41b899cc458c96fc0c523ce384aa70ab/R/import.r#L81) (but it’s worth noting that this is only called when the user is either in interactive mode, or passing a parameter that’s discouraged anyway).

Comment: `sapply` is fine when using `simplify=FALSE`.  To get the same output as `sapply(letters[1:3], "(", simplify=FALSE)` with `lapply`, you'd have to be redundant `setNames(lapply(letters[1:3], "("), letters[1:3])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Feel free to edit.)

The following functions should be handled with care (which does not necessarily mean they are not *suitable* for programming):

- Functions whose outputs do not have a consistent output class depending on the inputs: `sapply`, `mapply` (by default)
- Functions whose internal behavior is different depending on the input length: `sample`, `seq`
- Functions that evaluate some of their arguments within environments: `$`, `subset`, `with`, `within`, `transform`.
- Functions that go against normal environment usage: `attach`, `detach`, `assign`, `<<-`
- Functions that allow partial matching: `$`
- Functions that only make sense in interactive usage: `browser`, `recover`, `debug`, `debugonce`, `edit`, `fix`, `menu`, `select.list`
- Functions that can be a threat (virus) if used with user inputs: `source`, `eval(parse(text=...))`, `system`.

Also, to some extent, every function that generates warnings rather than errors. I recommend using `options(warn = 2)` to turn all warnings into errors in a programming application. Specific cases can then be allowed via `suppressWarnings` or `try`.

Comment: Interestingly, since R 3.1.0 partial matching of `data.frame` column names gives a warning, see [NEWS](http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/NEWS).

Comment: ...but not lists (for example `cars$d` v.s. `as.list(cars)$d`), sigh.

Answer (score 2):

This is in answer to the comment after the question by the poster. This function inputs a function and returns the bad functions found with their line number.  It can generate false positives but they are only warnings anways so that does not seem too bad. Modify `bad` to suit.

```
badLines <- function(func) {
    bad <- c("sapply", "subset", "attach")
    regex <- paste0("\\b", bad, "\\b")
    result <- sort(unlist(sapply(regex, FUN = grep, body(func), simplify = FALSE)))
    setNames(result, gsub("\\b", "", names(result), fixed = TRUE))
}
badLines(badLines)

## sapply1  subset  attach sapply2 
##       2       2       2       4
```

Comment: Some people might find the `lint` package useful for this kind of code checking. It is flexible enough that you can define your own rules. It has a pretty steep learning curve and poor documentation/support though.

Comment: @flodel Nice tip about the `lint` package.  I just tried `lint(dir("mypackage/R", full.names = TRUE))` and it threw up a load of stuff I hadn't spotted before.